# Trying to use a function that is in my context provider file

Tags: reactjs, react-context, react-lifecycle

I am using Context-Api and am trying to use a function provided from my file in a lifecycle method. the function isnt wrapped in a consumer of course so i looked at the documentation and set value to context. this still isnt working.Everyting is working in my return of my class component but component did mount does not work.

```
import { ProductConsumer } from '../context';

export default class Details1 extends Component
componentDidMount() {
    let value = this.context;
    let id = this.props.match.params.id;
    value.handleDetail(id);
  }

render() {
{value => {
          const {
            id,...} = value.detailProduct;
    return (
      <ProductConsumer>
        {value => {
My Component
 </ProductConsumer>

 export const Details = () => (
  <Product.Consumer>
    {context =>
      <Details1 context={context}/>

    }
  </Product.Consumer>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either wrap the component with the consumer, passing it the function as a prop, or (better - ) convert your component to a functional component, using the `useContext` hook to get the values from your context.

```js
import React, { useContext } from "react"; 
import someContext from "./context-path";

const MyComponent = () => {
  const { myFunction } = useContext(someContext);
  ...
};
```

Comment: How can i wrap a lifecycle method in a consumer?

Comment: Not the lifecycle method, but the class component itself

Comment: It is wrapped in a product consumer but this.props.context returns null in my Component Did mount but works in my components elements. Let met update this with the full component

Comment: It's not enough to just wrap with a consumer, the consumer should receive a function as its children.
The function receives the values given by the provider and returns whatever you want to render.

<MyContext.Consumer>
  {value => /* render something based on the context value */}
</MyContext.Consumer>